# Restricting access to a subdirectory on linux

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a way to make a directory accessible only to its parent directories. That is, suppose you have two directories, `A` and `B`, at the same level in the file hierarchy. Now suppose that you have a directory `A'` which is a subdirectory of `A`. I'd like to enforce that `A` is able to access the contents of `A'` but `B` is not.

My problem is that I'd like to use a library (directory `A`) which builds on top of a legacy version of another library (directory `A'`). At the same time, I want to be able to use the newest version of this legacy library (directory `B`). I want to make sure that people aren't somehow using library `A` and linking against new library `B` by enforcing that library `A` must use library `A'`.

I could just link `A` against library `B`, but then I'm risking compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about a directory accessing a directory?  Users (their processes) access directories, not other directories.

Comment: Does my edit clarify?

Comment: You're making the mistake [Raymond Chen describes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx): your problem is trying to keep two versions of a library on one computer, and you've assumed the solution has something to do with restricting access to directories.  You'll get much better answers if you ask your real question ("How do I make program A use lib-1.0 but everything else use lib-2.0?") instead.

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Use groups permissions,

suppose you have a group 'foo' and another group 'bar'
then

```
   /
   |
   +-A
   | |
   | +- A'
   |
   +-B
```

- `chgrp -R bar B` to set the group permission for subdirectory B.
- `chgrp -R foo A` to set the group permission for subdirectory A.

And make certain users be a member of group 'foo' so they will have access to A and its child subdirectories underneath it. Now, users who belong to group 'bar' will have no access to A and its related subdirectories either.

Comment: I don't want users to have restricted access. There is already a group in use to restrict a subset of users to have access to this directory containing `A` and `B`. I'll edit my response to further clarify my problem and goals.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Only a running program can access a directory; a directory cannot "access" another directory.

When you launch a program, your user account becomes the owner of that running process (if you run `ps -fa`, you see your UID on all of your programs)<sup>1</sup>.

When that process attempts to read a file, the system compares the process owner with the permissions on the file; if the user is allowed read permission, then the read succeeds; otherwise, it fails.

In the case of Program A trying to link against a library, the filesystem permissions on `/path/to/LibraryX` are compared against the process owner of Program A.  Even though the file `/path/to/ProgramA` has permissions set on it, those aren't considered when the *already running* instance of Program A attempts to read `/path/to/LibraryX`.  Permissions are only checked against the process owner.

---

[1] - The exception to this is programs with the setuid bit turned on. When you launch those programs (for example, `passwd`), then the process owner becomes the file's owner rather than yourself.  This is why `passwd` can edit `/etc/shadow` even though your user account can't: it always runs as root.